# C# SocketAsyncEventArgs - SendPacket

Tags: c#

I'm currently changing my server code, from TcpListener to SocketAsyncEventArgs. I'm using this great code of Stan Kirk (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod). Problem, that I currently vie; is that my server, short after Accepting new connection, instead of RECEIVING must SEND a packet of 10 bytes. (byte[] _packet = new byte[10] { 10, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1 };) I'm not quite sure how to do it. May anyone help me, in writing an easy SendPacket function, so I may easily send my byte arrays into the incoming socket?

Comment: The code you linked to calls `StartSend(...);` inside `ProcessReceive`, you can probably just call the same method somewhere inside `ProcessAccept`. But most likely this is not all your app needs to do and you actually need a certain state machine in your code. Why don't you read the entire article and comments carefully? Method names indicate what they are doing rather clearly IMO.

Comment: That article is almost 7 years old... be careful... I question if you really need to switch to `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. Specifically, have you *measured* high GC associated with `IAsyncResult` instances? If not, changing API is pointless. Anyway, if you still feel the need to continue, a rather clever head on the PFX team wrote [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/12/15/awaiting-socket-operations/) which makes working with `SocketAsyncEventArgs` a (small amount) easier by providing `async/await` powers.

Comment: Don't use `SocketAsyncEventArgs` unless you have a thorough understanding of TCP/IP programming in general and socket operations on Windows in particular. Does your server have observable performance issues? Can you prove those are related to the use of `TcpListener` rather than anything else? Are you already using asynchronous I/O rather than one-thread-per-client? If not, don't use `SocketAsyncEventArgs` but focus on the obvious issues first, otherwise the cost isn't justified.